# How to change devtools language in Firefox to English, while having the display in another language?

Tags: firefox, devtools

I prefer having my default language in Firefox be Hebrew, but I would like the devtools to be in English. By default, devtools is set to have the same language as the rest of the browser interface. I am trying to find an about:config setting that will change that, or an add-on.